# Network latency & Performance for inter subnet traffic in a AZ

Tags: subnet, amazon-vpc

My current local DC deployment has 2 subnets inside a datacenter where data is injected to the instances on a subnet A and then the instance is migrated to subnet B to serve traffic
We need to migrate this to AWS.
As per my current plan, the ingestion pipeline remains in subnet A but i launch the ec2 instance for storage in subnet B (this is the instance that is moved from A to B in local datacenter). And my ingestion pipeline saves the data directly to the instance in subnet B (& there is no need to copy over/move the instance from A to B). The instance type of the storage ec2 instance is instance store.

Some in the team are suggesting to have 2 NICs for the storage ec2 instance (1 each for subnet A and B). I don't understand why one should do this. Are there any latency or security or performance improvements for doing this way of using 2 nics 1 each for a subnet?